# how to display echo when using dropzone

Tags: php, ajax, response, dropzone

I am trying to get an echo from php when uploading files with dropzone.

This is the html:

```
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```

My ajax call:

```
$(".dropzone").dropzone({

    url: '',                        
    success:function(file, response) {
    alert(response);
    }

});
```

The php:

```
$extensionName = explode(".", $_FILES["files"]["name"][0]); 
$extension = strtolower(end($extensionName));



if($SumStorage > $LimitStorage) { // if max available storage is reached

    echo 'out of storage';

    exit;
}
elseif($_FILES["file"]["size"] > $MaxUploadSize) { // if maxupload size is exceeded

    echo 'file too big';

    exit;

}
elseif(in_array($extension, $AllowedExts) == 0) { // if extension is not allowed

    echo 'extension not allowed';

    exit;

}
```

The elseif loop works without problem. I have set this restrictions only in php, not in dropzone.js itself! If filesize is too big, extension not allowed or whatever...he refuses to upload. But the problem is the echo: i always get a `0` if was not allowed for some reason and a `1` if is uploaded successfully.

But he should echo `file too big` or `extension not allowed` etc...

Comment: Did you sure to catch the file from $_FILES array in PHP?

Comment: The problem is only the echo. The checks in the loops are working fine

Comment: Delete all exit functions. And put to all lines `$error = 'extension not allowed;` instead of "exit". And check it below with "if" after all by die($error);

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your ajax cal like this :

```
$(".dropzone").dropzone({

    url: '',                        
    success:function(file, response) {
    // alert(response);
    $("dropzone").append(response);
    }

});
```

And in your php file try to use **return** and not **echo**.